# Calculating age by birthdate field in crm 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I need to write a global javascript code that calculates age by birthday field and call the function from a diffrent javascript file to the specific entity.
from some reason i get error message "CalculateAge is undefined" after i loaded my entity javascript file to the form.

This is what i write in the global file:

```js
CalculateAge: function (birthd)
{
    if (birthd == null) {
        return;}
    var today = new Date().getFullYear();
    year1 = birthd.getFullYear();
    return (today-year1);
}
```

This is what i write in my entity file that i am loading to the form:

```js
function onLoad() {

        var birthDate = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("el_birth_date").getValue();
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("el_age").setValue(CalculateAge(birthDate));

    }
```

---

I am new in Javascript.. Can ypu please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JavaScript code you are using to calculate the age is not correct, it doesn't consider the month and the day.
A correct version is this one:

```js
function CalculateAge(birthday, ondate) {
   // if ondate is not specified consider today's date
   if (ondate == null) { ondate = new Date(); }
   // if the supplied date is before the birthday returns 0
   if (ondate < birthday) { return 0; }
   var age = ondate.getFullYear() - birthday.getFullYear();
   if (birthday.getMonth() > ondate.getMonth() || (birthday.getMonth() == ondate.getMonth() && birthday.getDate() > ondate.getDate())) { age--; }
   return age;
}
```

and can be used as:

```js
var birthday = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_birthday").getValue();
var age = CalculateAge(birthday);
alert(age);
// age on 1st January 2000, JavaScript Date() object contains months starting from 0
var testdate = new Date(2000, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
var testage = CalculateAge(birthday,testdate);
alert(testage);
```

If you get CalculateAge is not defined, probably you didn't include the webresource containing your function inside the form. If you have two JS web resources (one containing the function, the other one containing the onLoad event) both need to be included inside the form.

If you are in a CRM version that has the issue of the asynchronous javascript loading, it's better to include the CalculateAge function in the same file as the onLoad event, but if you prefer keep them separate check this blog post: [Asynchronous loading of JavaScript Web Resources after U12/POLARIS](http://develop1.net/public/post/Asynchronous-loading-of-JavaScript-Web-Resources-after-U12POLARIS.aspx)

The JavaScript function comes from my blog post: [Calculate age in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011](http://www.crmanswers.net/2013/03/calculate-age-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm.html)

Comment: Thank you! i did it and its working now.. but unfortunately i have another problem now.. i need to define age field to not save the data inserted in the DB so i wrote this in the entity JS file: Xrm.Page.getAttribute("el_age").setSubmitMode("never"); ---- The problem is when i save the form on the first time the value in age field is deleted after a few seconds and when i save it again its OK.. can you help? –